# How can I prove that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\:\sin\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)$ diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have tried all of the series tests that I know of, but I can't seem to find an answer. According to wolfram alpha, it is possible using the comparison test, however I can't figure out what I would compare the series with to show that it diverges.

Comment: The series diverges rather than converges. I believe using the limit comparison test with $b_n = 1/n$ will tell you this.

Comment: @Glare Thanks, I see that it diverges. I have fixed the question. How can I show that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}\le \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }sin\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)\:$?

Comment: The limit comparison test states that if $a_n,b_n\geq 0$ and $\lim a_n/b_n = c$ a positive finite number, then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ either both converge or both diverge. My earlier comment was suggesting you put $a_n = \sin(n/(n^2+1))$, check $a_n/b_n$ has finite limit, and then conclude $\sum a_n$ diverges because $\sum b_n = \sum 1/n$ diverges. The ordinary comparison test is a little trickier because you have to be careful with the inequalities.

Comment: @Glare Sorry for wasting your time with this question, can I get this post flagged to be deleted? I made a lot of mistakes asking this

Comment: You can delete it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of Matthew Pilling's comment, we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)}{1/n} &\stackrel{L.H.}{=} 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1-n^2}{(n^2+1)^2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)}{-1/n^2} \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^4-n^2}{(n^2+1)^2}\cos\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right) \\
&= 1 >0
\end{align*}
Thus, by the limit comparison test, since the harmonic series diverges, we have that
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}\right)$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

WolframAlpha in fact says that, by the Comparison Test, this series **diverges**.

[image]

Comment: Wow... I am not sure where I got converges from to be completely honest. What would I use the comparison test with? The harmonic series is not less than our series, is it?

Comment: You wanna use Limit Comparison Test, not Direct Comparison Test. No inequalities are involved with LCT.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thank you, Turns out this post was just mistake after mistake

Comment: The techniques and strategies I remember the most in math are usually those that follow my mistakes. Embrace them :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any $n\in\mathbb N$:
$$\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{n}{n^2+n^2}\le \frac{n}{n^2+1} \le 1$$
Furthermore, $\sin x\ge\frac{x}{2}$ for $0\le x\le 1$. Therefore:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sin \frac{n}{n^2+1} \ge \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \infty$$